# How to write code just for debug mode in MFC vs2005

Tags: mfc, debugging, macros

I want to define some member variable and some code just in Debug Mode,
When change to Release mode, they will not appear.

I know I can use #ifdef xxx to do this task.

My question is : is there any handy macro provided by MFC to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
```

Visual Studio defines the _DEBUG macro when building Debug flavor of your application.